update-initramfs command error
I run Ubuntu 24.04.1.
I encounter this error below when i execute the command: update-initramfs -u -k all
filip@ubuntu-pc:~$ sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.11.10-061110-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sda4
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.11.0-rt7
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-file.c:136 zstd_decompress_block: zstd: Restored data doesn't match checksum
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sda4
I: (UUID=0616e543-f102-49bc-98e5-c6b28c97c30f)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
depmod: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-file.c:136 zstd_decompress_block() zstd: Restored data doesn't match checksum


Can you try if this also gave error?  sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r) -b $HOME This creates a new initrid and save it in your $HOME so it is not destruvtive.

I reinstalled the RT kernel and now I don't get any errors.
